# I wrote this 20-questions program in Java for an assignment using switch statements

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

I wrote this program that is meant to play a variant of 20 questions with around 60 decisions. I used switch statements to do this, and wrote it like so:

```
static void Livinganimal() {
    System.out.println("Does it have feathers, fur, or neither?");
            String user = get.nextLine();
    user = user.toLowerCase();
    switch(user){
        case "feathers":
            FeathersQuestions();
            break;
        case "fur":
            Furquestion();
            break;
        case "neither":
            askneither();
            break;
        default:
            wronginput();
    }
}

static void FeathersQuestions() {
    System.out.println("is it bigger than a soccer ball?");
            String user = get.nextLine();
    user = user.toLowerCase();
   switch(user){
        case "yes":
            doesitfly();
            break;
        case "no":
            doesiteatmeat();
            break;
        default:
            wronginput();
    }

}

static void doesitfly() {
    System.out.println("Does it fly?");
           String user = get.nextLine();
    user = user.toLowerCase();
    switch(user){
        case "yes":
            doesithuntprey();
            break;
        case "no":
            doesitswim();
            break;
        default:
            wronginput();
    }
}

static void doesithuntprey() {
    System.out.println("Does it hunt prey?");
            String user = get.nextLine();
    user = user.toLowerCase();
    switch(user){
        case "yes":
            isitosprey();
            break;
        case "no":
            isitcrested();
            break;
        default:
            wronginput();
    }
}
```

Obviously it is much longer than that, but this is a segment to give an idea. I made each their own method to easily call each other and not get it confused. I am now told that because we haven't covered using multiple methods and such in class I cannot submit it in this form, and everything must be within the main method. Is there anyway I can transfer a fully formed code in this current makeup, and make it all under one main method?

Comment: It seems a little perverse that you are being instructed to follow the poor practice of having a really large, complex method, instead of the good practice of breaking code into easily understandable chunks.

Comment: yeah I agree, that why I wrote it the original way. But, that how our education system goes I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunate, since your approach is better. But I guess you could create while loop with big switch - for all 20 questions. Now after user answers your question, instead of calling methods, you would just set some variable to signal which question are you going to ask next. Then check this variable in that big switch statement. I hope you get my idea.

But if you are asking if you can just simply copy-paste this into main method somehow then I think no, you probably have some rewriting to do.

**Edit:** I mean, you can copy-paste, but still you have to rewrite methods calls to setting that variable.

Also, save this version of the code because you never know, maybe your teacher will decide he wants you all to rewrite it using methods, once you cover that topic in class. Also note that convention in java is camel case, so you should name methods doesItHuntPrey() instead of doesithuntprey().